# Любоваться кем-то или на кого-то?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Не помню, было это или нет, но поиск ничего не дал, поэтому рискну спросить.
Как правильно говорить: "Любоваться кем-то" или "на кого-то"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ЛЮБОВАТЬСЯ, -буюсь, -буешься; нсв. **кем-чем** и (разг.) *на кого-что*.
Рассматривать кого-, что-л. с восхищением, удовольствием. Л. выправкой офицера. Л. на смышлёного ребёнка.

Испытывать удовольствие, восхищение, наблюдая чью-л. деятельность, поступки и т.п. Л. работой большого мастера. Л. на игру любимой команды. Л. движениями спортсмена. < Любование, -я; ср. Л. природой.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно и так и так. ЛЮБОВАТЬСЯ (кем-чем) и ЛЮБОВАТЬСЯ (на кого-на что)
любуюсь, любуешься, несов. (к полюбоваться). 1. кем-чем. на кого-что. Рассматривать, созерцать кого-нибудь,что-нибудь, получая эстетическое удовольствие. Любоваться природой. Любоваться на восход солнца. "И долго сладостной картиной он любовался." Лермонтов. 2. кем-чем. Испытывать удовлетворение, восхищение при взгляде на кого-что-нибудь. Любоваться на подрастающих сыновей. Любоваться на счастливую жизнь молодой четы. || на себя, собою, чем-нибудь своим. Испытывать чувство радостного самоудовлетворения от чего-н. (неодобрит.) "Полюбуйтесь на него!". Любоваться на себя в зеркало. Любоваться своим произведением. Любоваться своей ловкостью. Любоваться собой.